# Casting a vote for a good answer

Tags: support, voting

I am confused about the process of casting a vote for someone who helped me (he is a good teacher). How can this be done?

Comment: If he provided you a good answer, give him an [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up)!

Comment: Read the [faq] which explains it all

Comment: You can start by NOT calling stackoverflow SACKoverflow ;-)

Comment: First things first: investigate the use of punctuation so that your entire question is not a single sentence.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40399/questions-favorite-vs-upvote

Comment: Note that you can only upvote if you have at least 15 reputation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a new user, the best way to reward the person whose answer helps you the most with your question is to **accept their answer on your question**. How to do this is explained in the FAQ under ["How do I ask questions here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). This lets other people know you have received a good answer, and give a reputation reward (15 rep) to the person who posted that answer. Accepting your answers also gives you a small reputation reward (2 rep).

Once you have at least 15 reputation, you can also **vote up questions and answers** that you think are especially useful. This also gives the poster a reputation reward for providing a useful post (up-votes give 5 rep to someone asking a useful question, and 10 rep to someone providing a useful answer).